# DataGrid Web Forms EditCommand/UpdateCommand. How to get changed value in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I've got a problem with my DataGrid's Edit command.

Here's my DataGrid:

http://imgur.com/0nmDJX0

and now i would like to edit my Title:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta38G.jpg

How can i get the "abc" value?

((TextBox) e.Item.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text still gives me the old value "sdfsd".

How can i get that "abc" value from textbox? I store my records to XML so all i need is to get these edited values.

Thanks.

Comment: Have u posted the data back ?

Comment: I am just trying to follow this tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/example-of-datagrid-in-Asp-Net/. I just dont get how is she updating values. All i can see is she's just updating records with old values :o.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the exact same thing on the exact same sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not binding your data on every page load.  If you do that, your new values are reloaded with old values before your event handler runs.

In my case, I just needed to put the BindData() inside the if (!Page.IsPostBack) block

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}
```